# how does Cordova plugin work under the hood?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

My question is  very basic :

**Can anyone tell how Cordova Plugins work?**

Specially I want to know about how plugin takes input from WebView and delegates it to native system and gives result back to web view.

**And Which android classes are responsible for this
or to be more specific How all this magic happens under the hood?**

I would be good if someone  provide some basic understanding because I'm not able to find any documentation and I want  some Insight into it before further going.

Answer (score 2):

I think that cordova uses the method 'addJavascriptInterface' of the class WebView to link Javascript code with Java code:

[addJavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))

I have searched this method in the files of a cordova project (after add android platform) and I have found it in the file 'SystemWebViewEngine.java' and also in others files.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugin is add-on code that provides JavaScript interface to native components. They allow your app to use native device capabilities beyond what is available to pure web apps. 
Plugin will internally have native code to communicate to device features like open camera, accessing files in device etc. 
Custom plugins can be created, refer https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/plugin-development/android/

http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/

In native code for android, you will have intents that can launch device features. Refer https://developer.android.com/

Now when developing hybrid apps, plugin will contain both js code, native code(java for android and objective-C for iOS)

When your app calls the plugin's JavaScript API, it is redirected to the underlying plugin native code that implements that API on the device. For example, the JavaScript API is redirected to Java code on an Android device or to Objective C code on an iOS device.

You can extract the plugin and check the code for better understanding.